# ¿Como mostrar año consulta ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy implementando reportes semanales tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT fecha_muestra, 
label, 
seiz_traf, 
call_comp_traf, 
answ_traf, 
TO_CHAR(fecha_muestra,'IW') AS SEMANA 
FROM V_GF_DATA_MSC_TRAF 
WHERE TO_CHAR(fecha_muestra,'IW')='40' 
AND TO_CHAR (fecha_muestra, 'mi') = '00' 
ORDER BY fecha_muestra ASC, label ASC
```

La cual me trae la semana 40, pero tengo un problema que a la hora de ejecutar la consulta me trae la semana 40 de todos los años y quisiera que me muestre el de cada año

Esta es un ejemplo de la salida que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál sería tu resultado esperado?

Comment: Que me traiga los registros de acuerdo a la semana que se encuentre en curso y del año actual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con este codigo para que te retorne todo lo del 2018 semana 40.

El problema es que en la condicion WHERE debes especificar el AÑO para que no te devuelva lo de los años anteriores. En este ejemplo se añade la columna ANIO y ademas se modifica la clausula WHERE para que devuelva solo el 2018.

Si quieres puedes modificar el  `AND  to_number(to_char(fecha_muestra, 'HH24')) = '2018'` para que te devuelva el año actual y no debas modificar la consulta año a año. `AND  to_number(to_char(fecha_muestra, 'YYYY')) = to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'))`

```
   SELECT fecha_muestra, 
    label, 
    seiz_traf, 
    call_comp_traf, 
    answ_traf, 
    TO_CHAR(fecha_muestra,'IW') AS SEMANA ,
to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')) as ANIO
    FROM V_GF_DATA_MSC_TRAF 
    WHERE TO_CHAR(fecha_muestra,'IW')='40' 
    AND TO_CHAR (fecha_muestra, 'mi') = '00' 
AND  to_number(to_char(fecha_muestra, 'YYYY')) = '2018'
    ORDER BY fecha_muestra ASC, label ASC
```

Comment: 'HH24' en el to_char te devuelve la hora y eso no es lo que necesitas, deberías poner 'YYYY' o 'RRRR'

Comment: ahi si estimado, correguido el problema, gracias por la aclaracion